# Session timeout stuck in loop

Tags: php

I'm stuck in a session timeout loop,
Once my session times out i can't sign back in

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 300)) {
    header("location:../index.php");
    exit();
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
?>
```

here is where I included the timeout.php

```
 <?php
//$now = 0;
if (isset($_REQUEST['err'])){
$now = $_REQUEST['err'];
}
?>
<?php
session_start();
include('../includes/session_timeout.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['isactive'])){
    header('location: index.php?e=li');
}
include('../../administrator/includes/constants.php');
include('../includes/functions.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['p'])){
    $cmd = $_REQUEST['p'];
}else{..........etc
```

Comment: Where is this code located? In your `index.php`-file?

Comment: no its not in the same page its been directed too

Comment: **Standard question number one:** Is there a `session_start()` in that code????

Comment: is this code included on index.php? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: index.php is the login page, the timeout.php is included in my controlpanel.php

Comment: Byron: Please add all code amendments to the Question (using the edit link) Non of us can read code in a comment

Comment: We also need to see how and when this code is executed. Just showing us a small snippet doesn't really help us, since the snippet itself doesn't really have any issues on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to unset your session variable before redirecting

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 300)) {
unset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']);
header("location:../index.php");
exit();
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

Comment: Consider accepting it as the answer if it worked for you